# How to "configure host" in MegaRaid Storage manager 13.01.04.00

Tags: vmware-esxi

### Context

I have created a virtual machine on ESxi host and installed Megaraid Storage manager on the virtual machine. I can see localhost discovered on MSM but when I configure Esxi host IP and try discovering the host I get error " Servers could not be found because server may be down or server not installed in the host system"

### Question

Am I missing something from installing or have followed the wrong process? can someone please help on this.

Comment: You installed the Megaraid Storage manager on a VM so that you could manage the storage of the host? If so, that's probably not going to work. Does the host have any embedded management tool, like ILO or iDRAC?

Comment: this is a UCS server it has ucs manger configured for the host system (esxi host).

Answer (score 1):

In order to use MegaRAID Storage Manager (MSM) remotely the following steps should be completed **before** attempting discovery:

1. LSI SMIS Provider VIB (`lsiprovider`) should be downloaded and installed on the ESXi Host where RAID adapter is located and the host restarted.
2. `CIM Server` on ESXi host under Configuration->Security Profile should be set to `Start and Stop with host` and be in a `Running` state.
3. Firewall rules for `CIM Server` on the same page should allow inbound connections for `CIM Server`, `CIM Secure Server` and `CIM SLP`
4. Status of RAID Adapter should be visible in Health Settings under Storage.

Within MSM, discovery options should be set to `Display all the ESXi-CIMOM servers in the network of local server`, saved and only then discovery attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Having done this exact scenario on 2 different servers I can vouch that installing the MSM on a VM to manage the health of the RAID card on the host is very much doable.

Peter Zhabin is absolutely correct with his instructions on needing to install the VIB and setting up the CIM service and firewall rules.  However there are a couple gotchas in those seemingly easy instructions.  Before installing the VIB make sure to change your host acceptance level to "community supported" and enter maintenance mode. Also be sure to install the vib using the the "no-sig-check" parameter.  Lastly there is a tricky step needed on the VM guest so that it can communicate with the host.

On your Windows virtual machine, you need to edit the hosts file so it can communicate with the esx host. Right click on Notepad and select “Run as Administrator.” Open your system hosts file, which can be found at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc. You will need to select “all file types” to be able to see it. Add the IP address for both the hostname and the FQDN of your ESXi host.

The 2 resources I used to get this working are below, take a look through them you should have no issue getting your MSM up and running.

https://serenity-networks.com/how-to-install-lsi-megaraid-storage-manager-msm-on-vmware-esxi-5-5/

https://tinkertry.com/esxi-5-1-can-run-lsi-megaraid-in-a-vm

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's still of any value for you, or if your problem was connected to the VM, but anyhow; maybe someone else finds it useful.

I had the same error message, and the following resolved the issue for me (on a HP workstation without a VM installed):

The "MSMFramework" service ("MegaRAID Storage Manager Framework Service") was not started, instead, startup type was set to "Automatic". So I simply started the service (I don't know why it was not running, though), and then it worked.